# Union-Find algorithm and determining whether an edge belongs to a cycle in a graph

Tags: graph, cycle, depth-first-search, union-find

I'm reading a book about algorithms ("Data Structures and Algorithms in C++") and have come across the following exercise:

> Ex. 20. Modify `cycleDetectionDFS()` so that it could determine whether a particular edge is part of a cycle in an undirected graph.

In the chapter about graphs, the book reads:

> Let us recall from a preceding section that depth-first search
>   guaranteed generating a spanning tree in which no elements of `edges`
>   used by `depthFirstSearch()` led to a cycle with other element of `edges`.
>   This was due to the fact that if vertices *v* and *u* belonged to `edges`,
>   then the *edge(vu)* was disregarded by `depthFirstSearch()`. A problem
>   arises when `depthFirstSearch()` is modified so that it can detect
>   whether a specific *edge(vu)* is part of a cycle (see Exercise 20).
>   Should such a modified depth-first search be applied to each edge
>   separately, then the total run would be O(E(E+V)), which could turn
>   into O(V^4) for dense graphs. Hence, a better method needs to be
>   found.
>
> The task is to determine if two vertices are in the same set. Two
>   operations are needed to implement this task: finding the set to which
>   a vertex *v* belongs and uniting two sets into one if vertex *v* belongs
>   to one of them and *w* to another. This is known as the *union-find
>   problem*.

Later on, author describes how to merge two sets into one in case an edge passed to the function `union(edge e)` connects vertices in distinct sets.

However, still I don't know how to quickly check whether an edge is part of a cycle. Could someone give me a rough explanation of such algorithm which is related to the aforementioned union-find problem?

Answer (score 1):

a rough explanation could be checking if a link is a backlink, whenever you have a backlink you have a loop, and whenever you have a loop you have a backlink (that is true for directed and undirected graphs).

A backlink is an edge that points from a descendant to a parent, you should know that when traversing a graph with a DFS algorithm you build a forest, and a parent is a node that is marked finished later in the traversal.

I gave you some pointers to where to look, let me know if that helps you clarify your problems.